# How would I update a single item in an ArrayList of items with data from Room? (android Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-room

I am fetching a list of dogs from an endpoint. Some of the attributes of the dog, color for example, are identified by id. The id's and colors corresponding to the id were all saved in a database when the app is opened. I am using MVVM architecture and assume that the model is consuming the response data correctly.

In the main screen of the app, I have a recyclerView that will populate with a list of dogs. when I fetch the list of dogs, I am returned the id of the dog's color as part of the dog object. The user isn't going want to see the id of the color, but the actual string value of the color corresponding to that id. I need to query the database with that id to get back the string value of the color to display to the UI.

My question is how would I go about doing this? The recyclerView adapter would be where the UI is updated, and I would need the position of the dog to know what color Id I am fetching, but I can't run that query from the adapter as it would lock up the main thread. I thought to create a function in the view model that would update that particular list item, but I think I would still need the position from the adapter. I'm not really sure how to proceed...

I hope my question isn't too confusing, I had a hard time figuring out how to ask! Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you might want to look at the *Query multiple tables* section of the Room docs: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#multiple-tables Basically it allows you to fetch data from several tables (e.g. the *Dogs* table and the *Colors* table, combining them through the *colour ID*) and you have a few options for ways to represent that data, from a special `DogAndColour` class to a `Map` (which is basically a set of `Pair`s, e.g. `Dog to Colour`). That way, your query can return all the data you need to display together

Comment: But if you only have the colours in your DB, and the dogs are stored elsewhere, you probably want the colour map stored in your `ViewModel` as a `LiveData` or `Flow`? `observe` that and push it to your adapter, and your adapter can use that current colour map as a lookup when displaying an item in the recycler. Otherwise, if you did want to hit the DB for data every time, you could use a coroutine to fetch it (with the IO dispatcher), and use one of the `notifyItemChanged` methods to update the item with the fetched colour (the position would be a local variable in the coroutine block)

Comment: @cactustictacs thanks for responding!! 
the database is for dog attributes - breed, color, health data, and titles from competition. the endpoint takes and returns these attributes by id, so we save all of this data to the database so we can have the data and fetch it as we need throughout the app. there's a crapload of breeds, colors, and titles, over 200 each.

I like your idea for hitting the db every time, but I'm not sure where I'd use the coroutine to fetch as I'd need the position.

Comment: It seems like we'd need to modify/update the list somehow before we send it to the adapter, either in the viewModel or the repo itself.

Comment: You'd do the fetch in `onBindViewHolder`, since that's the "set up a `ViewHolder` to display info for a specific item" bit. It's basically the same as fetching an image, or some other async operation - you have to do something with the data (like displaying it) whenever it finally arrives. Since `ViewHolder`s get reused while scrolling, you wouldn't want an old fetch updating the VH when it's meant to be displaying something else now - so you might want to put a `Job?` property in your VH class, store the coroutine when you launch it, and cancel it if you need to launch a new one for that VH

Answer (score 0):

You want to build proper query in your DAO and "join" values from another table, depending on color_id.

You are not allowed to do any queries at adapter level. Data passed to adapter must contain everything you need.

Joins and mappings are described here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data